# Using “respectively” in parenthesis in mathematical writing

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

In general, I know how to create a correct construction using *respectively.* But in the specific case when *respectively* is used together with double parentheses, I'm a bit lost. Which of the following constructions is the right one in this setting? Or are both of them correct?

- > An inverse limit of an inverse system of topological spaces (**resp. groups**) is a topological space (resp. group) together with a...
- > An inverse limit of an inverse system of topological spaces (**groups**) is a topological space (resp. group) together with a...

The second one is more natural for me.

Comment: Welcome to English Language SE. Due to our strict question-and-answer format, we prefer on question per question. If you want, you can ask your other questions separately, but usually it’s best if you wait a bit and learn from this question.

Comment: Related question on Writing SE on the usage of similar constructions in general: [Is elaborating the opposite case in brackets acceptable and clear?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44413/14946)

Comment: Nothing that exists inside of parentheses has any bearing whatsoever on the grammar of the surrounding text. You could put complete gibberish inside of parentheses, and the sentence itself would be grammatical. (Even if what was inside the parentheses didn't make any sense.) What sounds more natural is just style and personal opinion.